# Show original Op in unanswered questions tab

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

When I'm looking at the unanswered questions tab I would like to use the original poster as a guide to what I would like to answer. Currently the page only shows the last person who "modified" that question, making it impossible to see who posted until after I've clicked and opened the question.

I think it would be a good idea to put the last user who modified the question to the left of the original Op. This would give people an additional bit of information before deciding whether to click/try to answer the question.

Not only this, but it would make it consistent with the Questions tab.

Comment: And how is knowing who is the OP influencing you to choose a question?

Comment: Since what we want on the Stack Exchange network is good answers to good questions, bringing in the OP of the question should not be a relevant piece of information for deciding whether to answer a question. The only reason I can think of anyone doing this is in the search for getting more accepted answers (based on the likelihood of getting an accept seeing the rep of the OP, though in my opinion there is no correlation).

Comment: It's just a filter. If I see a question from an author with High Rep I almost always try to click it.  I often find those questions the most interesting (regardless if I can answer)

Comment: Just have a look at questions because they sound interesting. Not because particular users ask them. Every good question deserves an answer, no matter who it's from.

Comment: Not all questions can be determined to be interesting question from just the title. Knowing who is the op is an additional bit of knowledge to make a decision based on limited information (and screen space).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other commenters that who the OP is shouldn't matter. But, anyway you can sort of do this with the search function, which shows the OP instead the last editor.

For example, try searching for [`is:question answers:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0). This isn't quite the same as the unanswered tab since it excludes questions with un-upvoted answers, but it should hopefully be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: It's a good idea, and I'll try using it.  But the answers:0 is very restrictive, that was kind of the good thing about the unanswered tab.